# Lazy loading not active for new added object

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

I am using the `unit of work` with `repository pattern` in my ASP.NET project together with Entity Framework 6.

The problem I am facing is, is that when I add a new object to the database, its not directly active for `Lazy loading` when I call that same object again.

For example:

I have a `Attendance object` which contains 2 virtual links to `DayCode` and `Employee`.

```
public partial class Attendance
{
    public Attendance()
    {
        this.Id = -1;
        this.EmployeeId = -1;
        this.Present = false;
        this.Time = 0;
        this.Closed = false;
        this.Correction = false;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public bool Present { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> DayCodeId { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }
    public bool Correction { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual DayCode DayCode { get; set; }
}
```

My `DayCode` class:

```
public partial class DayCode
{
    public DayCode()
    {
        this.Id = -1;
        this.Code = "";
        this.Attendances = new HashSet<Attendance>();
    }

    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}
```

My click event of a button on my webpage:

```
    protected void btnSaveCorrection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Attendance attendance = GetItem();

        try
        {
            unitOfWork.AttendanceRepository.Add(attendance);
            unitOfWork.Save();
        }
        catch
        {
            ShowMessage("Problemen ondervonden, probeer opnieuw!", "alert alert-danger");
        }

        // Load attendances
        LoadAttendances(3); // Test Michael
        LoadCorrections(3); // Test Michael
    }
```

My `LoadCorrections` method:

```
    private void LoadCorrections(int employeeId) // Test _EmployeeId
    {
        //...

        Employee _employee = unitOfWork.EmployeeRepository.LoadItem(employeeId);

        int counter = 0;
        foreach (Attendance attendance in _employee.Attendances.Where(
                e => e.Correction && e.Date.Month == _Date.Month
            ).OrderBy(e => e.Date).ThenBy(e => e.Id))
        {
            _bodyRow = new BTableBodyRow();
            _bodyRow._CssClass = "";

            //...

            _cellBody = new BTableBodyCell();
            _cellBody._Content = attendance.DayCode.Code + " ( " + attendance.DayCode.Title + " )";

            //Here I get a nullreference exception!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            _cellBody._CssClass = "left";
            _bodyRow._BodyCells.Add(_cellBody);

            //...

            _bodyRows.Add(_bodyRow);

            counter++;
        }

        //...
    }
```

Do I have to update in some of way the `Lazy loading` or... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution reading the answer of [Entity Framework Code First not lazy loading after save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027657/entity-framework-code-first-not-lazy-loading-after-save)

The problem was that I only created a new instance of the POCO class and not the proxy.
In my Repository pattern I created a new virtual method `Create` which creates this proxy.

```
public virtual T Create()
{
    return this._dbSet.Create<T>();
}
```

And instead of creating a new instance of the attendance class using:

```
Attendance attendance = new Attendance();
```

I use the Repository pattern method `Create`:

```
Attendance attendance = unitOfWork.AttendanceRepository.Create();
```

Now the null reference exception is gone.